# a family of Pellian equations

Tags: nt.number-theory, diophantine-equations

I have a question concering the family of Pellian equations
$$x^2 - (k^2+1)y^2 = k^2.  \qquad    (*)$$

For an integer $k\geq 2$, the equation (*) has at least three classes of solutions
in integers, corresponding to the fundamental solutions
$(x_0,y_0) = (k, 0)$, $(k^2-k+1, k-1)$, $(k^2-k+1, -(k-1))$.
Each fundamental solution induces a sequence (class) of solutions by
$$ x+\sqrt{k^2+1}y = (x_0+\sqrt{k^2+1}y_0)(k+\sqrt{k^2+1})^{2m}. $$

For certain values of $k$, there are two additional classes
of solutions. E.g. for $k=2t^2$, we have also fundamental
solutions $(x_0,y_0) = (2t^3+t, \pm t)$, and additional
solutions occur also for $k=4s^3-4s^2+3s-1$,
for $k=F_{2n}$, and other polynomial or exponential subfamilies.
However, I am not able to find any example such that (*)
has more than five classes of solutions.

So, I am wondering does it make sense to state the conjecture
that for $k\geq 2$, equation `(*)` always have
exactly three or five classes of solutions
(e.g. 3 or 5 fundamental solutions).
Is there an obvious reason why should (or should not)
the number of fundamental solutions of (*) be bounded
by an absolute constant (independent on $k$)?

It is easy to see that each fundamental solution $(x_0,y_0)$
has to satisfy $|y_0| < k$, so the conjecture actually says
that there is at most one solution of equation (*) with
$0 < y < k-1$.

This question is related to the conjecture which
says that there does not exist a set of four
positive integer with the property that the
product of any two of them is 1 greater than a square
(see e.g. [Section 3.1 of Diophantine m-tuples page](http://web.math.pmf.unizg.hr/~duje/dn.html)
and references given there).

Edit (2.10.2022): In the recent paper by Maohua Le and Anitha Srinivasan, the conjecture is verified for $k=p^m q^n$, where $p,q$ are distinct odd primes and $m,n$ are positive integers (see https://web.math.pmf.unizg.hr/glasnik/forthcoming/pGM7053.pdf).

Comment: Let me mention that I have checked "the conjecture" for $k\leq 1000000$. In that range, there are 1045 $k$'s for which this equation has 5 classes of solutions, while for all other $k$'s there are 3 classes. It seems that the number of $k$'s such that $k \leq N$ and the equation has 5 classes of solutions is $O(\sqrt{N})$ (it seems that, asymptotically, the most on such cases comes from $k=2t^2$).


Comment: Just a simple observation: this equation is equivalent to $x^2+1=(y^2+1)(k^2+1)$, i.e., when the product of two numbers of the form $m^2+1$ is again a number of this form.

Comment: found slides from a nice talk by Keith Matthews http://www.numbertheory.org/pdfs/dujella_slides.pdf

Comment: The mentioned related conjecture that there does not exist a set of four positive integers with the property that the product of any two of them is 1 greater than a square was proved recently in the paper N. C. Bonciocat, M. Cipu, M. Mignotte, There is no Diophantine D(-1)-quadruple, J. London Math. Soc. 105 (2022), 63-99.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Oh, I think the answer is definitely yes!

Let $\{k \to x,y\}$ be any solution of $x^2 - (k^2+1)y^2 = k^2$, and let $K$ be the set of $k$ for which a solution has $0 < k < y-1$. In a paper recently
submitted to *Glasnik Matematicki* we call these solutions
*exceptional* solutions. Andrej's conjecture is that for any $k$ there is at most 1 exceptional solution.

One interesting result we obtain is that, if $k \in K$, then
$y < (2 - \sqrt{3})k$.

A particular feature of this Pell equation is its symmetry wrt $k$ and $y$. These are interchangeable, so for any solution $\{k \to x,y\}$ there is a corresponding solution $\{y \to x,k\}$.

It follows that if $k \neq y \pm{1}$, then either $k \in K$ or $y \in K$.

Now, for any $k \geq 2$, we have 3 particular solution classes $(x_n, y_n)$ with
$y_0 = \{0, k-1, -(k-1)\}$. For any $n > \{0, 0, 1\}$ we have $y_n > k-1$
and so $\{y_n \to x_n,k\}$ is exceptional, ie. $y_n \in K$.

We also need to consider $k=1$, for which there is just the one
class with $(x_0, y_0) = (1, 0)$ , $(x_1, y_1) = (3, 2)$ and so for
any $n > 1$ we have $y_n \in K$. For example $(x_2, y_2) = (17, 12)$ from
which we obtain exceptional solution $\{12 \to 17, 1\}$, and so $12 \in K$.

In our paper we call the corresponding set of exceptional solutions
"Type 1". But here let us simply define the set $K_1$ to be all of these
$y_n > k$ that we find from these 3 classes for any $k > 1$, and
from the one class for $k = 1$.

One property shared by all type 1 solutions, ie $\{k \to x, y\}$ with $k \in K_1$ is that either $(y^2 +1) | (x+y)$ or $(y^2 + 1) |(x-y)$.

Now, for any $k \in K_1$ we have a corresponding $\{k \to x,y\}$ for
which our Pell eqn has 2 additional solution classes, with fundamental solutions
$(x_0, y_0) = (x, \pm y)$. For any $n > \{0,1\}$ we then have $y_n > k-1$
and so $\{y_n \to x_n, k\}$ is exceptional, ie $y_n \in K$.

And of course we can apply the same process to any of these new $y_n$
*ad infinitum*, each $y_n$ seeding a forest of others. For example,
just considering $n = 1$ alone in each case, from $\{8 \to 18,\pm{2}\}, 8 \in K_1$ 
we obtain $\{546 \to 4402,8\}$ and $\{30 \to 242,8\}$, so $546, 30 \in K$,
and from $\{30 \to 242, \pm{8}\}$ we get $\{28928 \to 868322,242\}$ and
$\{112 \to 3362,30\}$, so $28928, 112 \in K$.

We call these "Type 2" solutions, so let's define $K_2$ to be all of
the $y_n$ found this way. These do not have the divisibility property that
was noted above for the $y_n \in K_1$.

In the paper we show that all 
exceptional solutions can be enumerated recursively in this
fashion, ie. that $K = K_1 \cup K_2$. This is done by showing any $k \in K$ can
be traced back to a root in $K_1$.

The enumeration
algorithm is given below. Solution classes are referred to as $0, -1, +1$, the interpretation of which I hope is reasonably clear!

**Proc *Enum_K:***

> Enum_K1(1,0)
> for k = 2 to $ \infty $
>
> > Enum_K1(k, 0)
> > Enum_K1(k, +1)
> > Enum_K1(k, -1)

**Proc *Enum_K1(k, class):***

> set $(x_0, y_0), (x_1, y_1)$ according to class
> n1 = if (class = -1 or k = 1) then 2 else 1
> for n = n1 to $\infty$
>
> > add $y_n$ to $K_1$
> > Enum_K2($y_n$, +1)
> > Enum_K2($y_n$, -1)

**Proc *Enum_K2(k, class):***

> set $(x_0, y_0), (x_1, y_1)$ according to class
> n1 = if (class = -1) then 2 else 1
> for n = n1 to $\infty$
>
> > add $y_n$ to $K_2$
> > Enum_K2($y_n$, +1)
> > Enum_K2($y_n$, -1)

To generate the solution sequences in any class, we note that each class has the same
recurrence relation:

> $R = 2k^2 + 1$
> $x_n = 2Rx_{n-1} - x_{n-2}$
> $y_n = 2Ry_{n-1} - y_{n-2}$

but of course have different initial conditions:

> $R = 2k^2 + 1, S = 2k, D = k^2 + 1$
> $K_1, class 0: (x_0, y_0) = (k, 0), (x_1, y_1) = (kR, kS)$
> $K_1, class +: (x_0, y_0) = (k^2-k+1, k-1)$
> $K_1, class -: (x_0, y_0) = (k^2-k+1,1-k)$
> $K_2, class +: (x_0, y_0) = (x_n, +y_n)$ for any $y_n \in K_1 \cup K_2$
> $K_2, class -: (x_0, y_0) = (x_n, -y_n)$   "  "
>
> and in all cases above $(x_1, y_1)$ satisfy
>
> > $x_1 = Rx_0 + DSy_0$
> > $y_1 = Ry_0 + Sx_0$

Now if Andrej's conjecture is true, and we believe it is, then each operation "*add* $y_n$" always adds a new $y_n$ to its list, and the two lists $K_1, K_2$ have
no common elements.

An implementation of *Enum_K* with a bailout parameter finds
that with $k <10^6$ we have $|K_1| = 882, |K_2| = 163, |K| = 1045$, and 
that every $k$ enumerated was unique. This agrees with Andrej's figure.

Comment: For `$k < 2^32$` we have $|K_1| = 48717, |K_2| = 1657, |K| = 50374$.
These were all verified to be unique, so Andrej's conjecture is
confirmed for `$k < 2^32$`, given that we accept that the enumeration
process finds all $k$. 


Comment: There are too many $k \in K$ to make verification practical for `$k < 2^64$`,
but for the record we believe that $|K_1| = 3,040,378,747$ and
$|K_2| = 1,725,632$.


Comment: My co-author Keith Matthews has made available a set of slides he used when giving a recent presentation based on our submitted paper. These can be found at http://www.numbertheory.org/pdfs/dujella_slides.pdf

Comment: Apologies, the bounds for $k$ above should read $2^{32}$ and $2^{64}$

Comment: Corrected mistake in the statement "One property shared by all $y_n \in K_1 \ldots $. The divisibility property involves $y_n^2 + 1$, not $y_n$.

Answer (score 8):

This is an interesting question. Let me explain why I believe that the answer is no.

Rewrite the equation in the form 
$$ (x-k)(x+k) = (k^2+1)y^2. $$
Interpreting this as an equation in the polynomial ring ${\mathbb Z}[k]$ and using unique factorization you end up with equations of the form 
$$ x - k = (k^2+1)A^2, \quad x + k = B^2, $$
which implies
$$ 2k = B^2 - (k^2+1)A^2. $$
The solution $A = 1$ and $B = k+1$ gives rise to one of yours.

In order to be able to find a lot more fundamental solutions you will have to substitute $k = f(t)$ for a polynomial $f$ that makes $k^2+1$ reducible. the simplest choice is $k = 2t^2$ since 
$$ k^2+1 = 4t^4 + 1 = (2t^2+1)^2 - 4t^2 = (2t^2+2t+1)(2t^2-2t+1). $$
Going through the game above will reveal your additional solution in this case.

If you substitute $ k = t + 2t^3$ (I hope I remember my calculations well), the polynomial $k^2+1$ splits into three quadratic factors. Whether the resulting Pell type equations have more solutions is difficult to check. But my impression is that of you can find many substitutions for which $k^2+1$ splits into many factors, chances are that you get more than 2*2+1 = 5 fundamental solutions. Where's Noam when you need him?

Comment: I swapped $A$ and $B$, it was not correct as it was.

Answer (score 2):

This question was brought to my attention yesterday. I would like to just post some pairs, the smallest 134 values of $k,$ for which there is a solution to $(1 + k^2)(1 + y^2) = 1 + x^2$ with $y \leq k-2.$ There are numerous sequences among the $k$ values. Simplest is $k = 2 t^2$ for integer $t.$ Next are linear recurrence  sequences, $k \in \{8, 30, 112, 418, 1560, \ldots \}$ such that $k_{j+2} = 4 k_{j+1} - k_j,$ for which $y$ is the previous element in the sequence. Or $k \in \{12, 119, 1178, 11661, \ldots \}$ such that $k_{j+2} = 10 k_{j+1} - k_j,$ for which $y$ is the previous element in the sequence. Also  $k \in \{12, 70, 408, 2378, \ldots \}$ such that $k_{j+2} = 6 k_{j+1} - k_j,$ for which $y=1.$ Then  $k \in \{8, 21, 55, 144, 377 \ldots \}$ such that $k_{j+2} = 3 k_{j+1} - k_j,$ the even-index Fibonacci numbers, for which $y=2.$ Lots of these things, if any two of them overlap at some huge $k$ value that would give a counterexample. So far, nothing, it is just nice to have something to grab onto other than factoring $k$ or $k^2 + 1.$ I am going to guess that most of this is covered in the work of Jim White, the talk I found by Matthews discussed a sort of Markov type tree of such $k,$ actually about three trees I think. Yes, in the talk by Matthews http://www.numbertheory.org/pdfs/dujella_slides.pdf we see the linear recurrence sequences above as single branches in one of the trees. Same as the way half the Fibonacci numbers are the slowest growing branch in the [Markov tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Markov_number)

Anyway, small $k:$

```
1     k: 8  y:  2   x:  18  k^2 + 1 =  5 13  y^2 + 1 =  5
2     k: 12  y:  1   x:  17  k^2 + 1 =  5 29  y^2 + 1 =  2
3     k: 18  y:  3   x:  57  k^2 + 1 =  5^2 13  y^2 + 1 =  2 5
4     k: 21  y:  2   x:  47  k^2 + 1 =  2 13 17  y^2 + 1 =  5
5     k: 30  y:  8   x:  242  k^2 + 1 =  17 53  y^2 + 1 =  5 13
6     k: 32  y:  4   x:  132  k^2 + 1 =  5^2 41  y^2 + 1 =  17
7     k: 50  y:  5   x:  255  k^2 + 1 =  41 61  y^2 + 1 =  2 13
8     k: 55  y:  2   x:  123  k^2 + 1 =  2 17 89  y^2 + 1 =  5
9     k: 70  y:  1   x:  99  k^2 + 1 =  13^2 29  y^2 + 1 =  2
10     k: 72  y:  6   x:  438  k^2 + 1 =  5 17 61  y^2 + 1 =  37
11     k: 80  y:  3   x:  253  k^2 + 1 =  37 173  y^2 + 1 =  2 5
12     k: 98  y:  7   x:  693  k^2 + 1 =  5 17 113  y^2 + 1 =  2 5^2
13     k: 105  y:  18   x:  1893  k^2 + 1 =  2 37 149  y^2 + 1 =  5^2 13
14     k: 112  y:  30   x:  3362  k^2 + 1 =  5 13 193  y^2 + 1 =  17 53
15     k: 119  y:  12   x:  1433  k^2 + 1 =  2 73 97  y^2 + 1 =  5 29
16     k: 128  y:  8   x:  1032  k^2 + 1 =  5 29 113  y^2 + 1 =  5 13
17     k: 144  y:  2   x:  322  k^2 + 1 =  89 233  y^2 + 1 =  5
18     k: 154  y:  3   x:  487  k^2 + 1 =  37 641  y^2 + 1 =  2 5
19     k: 162  y:  9   x:  1467  k^2 + 1 =  5 29 181  y^2 + 1 =  2 41
20     k: 200  y:  10   x:  2010  k^2 + 1 =  13 17 181  y^2 + 1 =  101
21     k: 203  y:  4   x:  837  k^2 + 1 =  2 5 13 317  y^2 + 1 =  17
22     k: 208  y:  21   x:  4373  k^2 + 1 =  5 17 509  y^2 + 1 =  2 13 17
23     k: 242  y:  11   x:  2673  k^2 + 1 =  5 13 17 53  y^2 + 1 =  2 61
24     k: 252  y:  32   x:  8068  k^2 + 1 =  5 13 977  y^2 + 1 =  5^2 41
25     k: 288  y:  12   x:  3468  k^2 + 1 =  5 53 313  y^2 + 1 =  5 29
26     k: 333  y:  4   x:  1373  k^2 + 1 =  2 5 13 853  y^2 + 1 =  17
27     k: 338  y:  13   x:  4407  k^2 + 1 =  5 73 313  y^2 + 1 =  2 5 17
28     k: 377  y:  2   x:  843  k^2 + 1 =  2 5 61 233  y^2 + 1 =  5
29     k: 392  y:  14   x:  5502  k^2 + 1 =  5 73 421  y^2 + 1 =  197
30     k: 408  y:  1   x:  577  k^2 + 1 =  5 13^2 197  y^2 + 1 =  2
31     k: 414  y:  5   x:  2111  k^2 + 1 =  101 1697  y^2 + 1 =  2 13
32     k: 418  y:  112   x:  46818  k^2 + 1 =  5^2 29 241  y^2 + 1 =  5 13 193
33     k: 450  y:  15   x:  6765  k^2 + 1 =  13 37 421  y^2 + 1 =  2 113
34     k: 495  y:  50   x:  24755  k^2 + 1 =  2 101 1213  y^2 + 1 =  41 61
35     k: 512  y:  16   x:  8208  k^2 + 1 =  5 13 37 109  y^2 + 1 =  257
36     k: 546  y:  8   x:  4402  k^2 + 1 =  241 1237  y^2 + 1 =  5 13
37     k: 578  y:  17   x:  9843  k^2 + 1 =  5 109 613  y^2 + 1 =  2 5 29
38     k: 612  y:  105   x:  64263  k^2 + 1 =  5 173 433  y^2 + 1 =  2 37 149
39     k: 616  y:  5   x:  3141  k^2 + 1 =  13 17^2 101  y^2 + 1 =  2 13
40     k: 648  y:  18   x:  11682  k^2 + 1 =  5 137 613  y^2 + 1 =  5^2 13
41     k: 684  y:  3   x:  2163  k^2 + 1 =  13 17 29 73  y^2 + 1 =  2 5
42     k: 697  y:  12   x:  8393  k^2 + 1 =  2 5 13 37 101  y^2 + 1 =  5 29
43     k: 722  y:  19   x:  13737  k^2 + 1 =  5 137 761  y^2 + 1 =  2 181
44     k: 737  y:  6   x:  4483  k^2 + 1 =  2 5 29 1873  y^2 + 1 =  37
45     k: 800  y:  20   x:  16020  k^2 + 1 =  29^2 761  y^2 + 1 =  401
46     k: 858  y:  72   x:  61782  k^2 + 1 =  5 29 5077  y^2 + 1 =  5 17 61
47     k: 882  y:  21   x:  18543  k^2 + 1 =  5^2 29^2 37  y^2 + 1 =  2 13 17
48     k: 968  y:  22   x:  21318  k^2 + 1 =  5^2 37 1013  y^2 + 1 =  5 97
49     k: 987  y:  2   x:  2207  k^2 + 1 =  2 5 61 1597  y^2 + 1 =  5
50     k: 1027  y:  6   x:  6247  k^2 + 1 =  2 5 29 3637  y^2 + 1 =  37
51     k: 1058  y:  23   x:  24357  k^2 + 1 =  5 13 17 1013  y^2 + 1 =  2 5 53
52     k: 1152  y:  24   x:  27672  k^2 + 1 =  5 13 17 1201  y^2 + 1 =  577
53     k: 1178  y:  119   x:  140187  k^2 + 1 =  5 13 37 577  y^2 + 1 =  2 73 97
54     k: 1196  y:  7   x:  8457  k^2 + 1 =  53 137 197  y^2 + 1 =  2 5^2
55     k: 1250  y:  25   x:  31275  k^2 + 1 =  1201 1301  y^2 + 1 =  2 313
56     k: 1352  y:  26   x:  35178  k^2 + 1 =  5 281 1301  y^2 + 1 =  677
57     k: 1365  y:  98   x:  133777  k^2 + 1 =  2 197 4729  y^2 + 1 =  5 17 113
58     k: 1428  y:  55   x:  78553  k^2 + 1 =  5 617 661  y^2 + 1 =  2 17 89
59     k: 1458  y:  27   x:  39393  k^2 + 1 =  5 17 89 281  y^2 + 1 =  2 5 73
60     k: 1560  y:  418   x:  652082  k^2 + 1 =  17 37 53 73  y^2 + 1 =  5^2 29 241
61     k: 1568  y:  28   x:  43932  k^2 + 1 =  5^3 13 17 89  y^2 + 1 =  5 157
62     k: 1590  y:  7   x:  11243  k^2 + 1 =  41 197 313  y^2 + 1 =  2 5^2
63     k: 1682  y:  29   x:  48807  k^2 + 1 =  5^3 13 1741  y^2 + 1 =  2 421
64     k: 1800  y:  30   x:  54030  k^2 + 1 =  1741 1861  y^2 + 1 =  17 53
65     k: 1815  y:  8   x:  14633  k^2 + 1 =  2 13 17 29 257  y^2 + 1 =  5 13
66     k: 1922  y:  31   x:  59613  k^2 + 1 =  5 397 1861  y^2 + 1 =  2 13 37
67     k: 1984  y:  252   x:  499972  k^2 + 1 =  13 29 53 197  y^2 + 1 =  5 13 977
68     k: 2040  y:  128   x:  261128  k^2 + 1 =  257 16193  y^2 + 1 =  5 29 113
69     k: 2048  y:  32   x:  65568  k^2 + 1 =  5 397 2113  y^2 + 1 =  5^2 41
70     k: 2059  y:  208   x:  428277  k^2 + 1 =  2 13 41^2 97  y^2 + 1 =  5 17 509
71     k: 2077  y:  80   x:  166173  k^2 + 1 =  2 5 641 673  y^2 + 1 =  37 173
72     k: 2112  y:  4   x:  8708  k^2 + 1 =  5 17 97 541  y^2 + 1 =  17
73     k: 2178  y:  33   x:  71907  k^2 + 1 =  5 449 2113  y^2 + 1 =  2 5 109
74     k: 2312  y:  34   x:  78642  k^2 + 1 =  5 449 2381  y^2 + 1 =  13 89
75     k: 2329  y:  8   x:  18777  k^2 + 1 =  2 61 173 257  y^2 + 1 =  5 13
76     k: 2378  y:  1   x:  3363  k^2 + 1 =  5 197 5741  y^2 + 1 =  2
77     k: 2450  y:  35   x:  85785  k^2 + 1 =  2381 2521  y^2 + 1 =  2 613
78     k: 2584  y:  2   x:  5778  k^2 + 1 =  37 113 1597  y^2 + 1 =  5
79     k: 2592  y:  36   x:  93348  k^2 + 1 =  5 13 41 2521  y^2 + 1 =  1297
80     k: 2618  y:  9   x:  23707  k^2 + 1 =  5^2 13 21089  y^2 + 1 =  2 41
81     k: 2738  y:  37   x:  101343  k^2 + 1 =  5 13 29 41 97  y^2 + 1 =  2 5 137
82     k: 2888  y:  38   x:  109782  k^2 + 1 =  5 29 97 593  y^2 + 1 =  5 17^2
83     k: 2907  y:  162   x:  470943  k^2 + 1 =  2 5^2 13 13001  y^2 + 1 =  5 29 181
84     k: 3038  y:  3   x:  9607  k^2 + 1 =  5 281 6569  y^2 + 1 =  2 5
85     k: 3042  y:  39   x:  118677  k^2 + 1 =  5 593 3121  y^2 + 1 =  2 761
86     k: 3200  y:  40   x:  128040  k^2 + 1 =  17 193 3121  y^2 + 1 =  1601
87     k: 3268  y:  9   x:  29593  k^2 + 1 =  5^2 13 17 1933  y^2 + 1 =  2 41
88     k: 3362  y:  41   x:  137883  k^2 + 1 =  5 13 17 53 193  y^2 + 1 =  2 29^2
89     k: 3528  y:  42   x:  148218  k^2 + 1 =  5 13 53 3613  y^2 + 1 =  5 353
90     k: 3567  y:  612   x:  2183007  k^2 + 1 =  2 5 13 97 1009  y^2 + 1 =  5 173 433
91     k: 3629  y:  10   x:  36471  k^2 + 1 =  2 401 16421  y^2 + 1 =  101
92     k: 3698  y:  43   x:  159057  k^2 + 1 =  5 757 3613  y^2 + 1 =  2 5^2 37
93     k: 3740  y:  21   x:  78629  k^2 + 1 =  41^2 53 157  y^2 + 1 =  2 13 17
94     k: 3872  y:  44   x:  170412  k^2 + 1 =  5 17 233 757  y^2 + 1 =  13 149
95     k: 3990  y:  200   x:  798010  k^2 + 1 =  29 37^2 401  y^2 + 1 =  13 17 181
96     k: 3999  y:  18   x:  72093  k^2 + 1 =  2 13 17 97 373  y^2 + 1 =  5^2 13
97     k: 4050  y:  45   x:  182295  k^2 + 1 =  17 41 101 233  y^2 + 1 =  2 1013
98     k: 4059  y:  70   x:  284159  k^2 + 1 =  2 17 173 2801  y^2 + 1 =  13^2 29
99     k: 4232  y:  46   x:  194718  k^2 + 1 =  5^2 41 101 173  y^2 + 1 =  29 73
100     k: 4418  y:  47   x:  207693  k^2 + 1 =  5^2 173 4513  y^2 + 1 =  2 5 13 17
101     k: 4431  y:  10   x:  44531  k^2 + 1 =  2 401 24481  y^2 + 1 =  101
102     k: 4608  y:  48   x:  221232  k^2 + 1 =  5 941 4513  y^2 + 1 =  5 461
103     k: 4802  y:  49   x:  235347  k^2 + 1 =  5 13^2 29 941  y^2 + 1 =  2 1201
104     k: 4872  y:  11   x:  53813  k^2 + 1 =  5 97 109 449  y^2 + 1 =  2 61
105     k: 4900  y:  495   x:  2425505  k^2 + 1 =  17 353 4001  y^2 + 1 =  2 101 1213
106     k: 5000  y:  50   x:  250050  k^2 + 1 =  13^2 29 5101  y^2 + 1 =  41 61
107     k: 5100  y:  5   x:  26005  k^2 + 1 =  37 113 6221  y^2 + 1 =  2 13
108     k: 5202  y:  51   x:  265353  k^2 + 1 =  5 1061 5101  y^2 + 1 =  2 1301
109     k: 5313  y:  242   x:  1285757  k^2 + 1 =  2 5 97 29101  y^2 + 1 =  5 13 17 53
110     k: 5408  y:  52   x:  281268  k^2 + 1 =  5 37 149 1061  y^2 + 1 =  5 541
111     k: 5618  y:  53   x:  297807  k^2 + 1 =  5^2 37 149 229  y^2 + 1 =  2 5 281
112     k: 5822  y:  1560   x:  9082322  k^2 + 1 =  5 2017 3361  y^2 + 1 =  17 37 53 73
113     k: 5832  y:  54   x:  314982  k^2 + 1 =  5^2 13 229 457  y^2 + 1 =  2917
114     k: 5842  y:  11   x:  64527  k^2 + 1 =  5 13 97 5413  y^2 + 1 =  2 61
115     k: 5848  y:  3   x:  18493  k^2 + 1 =  5 101 241 281  y^2 + 1 =  2 5
116     k: 6050  y:  55   x:  332805  k^2 + 1 =  13 61 101 457  y^2 + 1 =  2 17 89
117     k: 6272  y:  56   x:  351288  k^2 + 1 =  5 61 101 1277  y^2 + 1 =  3137
118     k: 6371  y:  12   x:  76717  k^2 + 1 =  2 17 577 2069  y^2 + 1 =  5 29
119     k: 6498  y:  57   x:  370443  k^2 + 1 =  5 17 389 1277  y^2 + 1 =  2 5^3 13
120     k: 6728  y:  58   x:  390282  k^2 + 1 =  5 17 37^2 389  y^2 + 1 =  5 673
121     k: 6765  y:  2   x:  15127  k^2 + 1 =  2 13 37 113 421  y^2 + 1 =  5
122     k: 6900  y:  288   x:  1987212  k^2 + 1 =  109 577 757  y^2 + 1 =  5 53 313
123     k: 6962  y:  59   x:  410817  k^2 + 1 =  5 37^2 73 97  y^2 + 1 =  2 1741
124     k: 7200  y:  60   x:  432060  k^2 + 1 =  73 97 7321  y^2 + 1 =  13 277
125     k: 7442  y:  61   x:  454023  k^2 + 1 =  5 17 89 7321  y^2 + 1 =  2 1861
126     k: 7525  y:  12   x:  90613  k^2 + 1 =  2 577 49069  y^2 + 1 =  5 29
127     k: 7688  y:  62   x:  476718  k^2 + 1 =  5 13 17 89 601  y^2 + 1 =  5 769
128     k: 7697  y:  154   x:  1185363  k^2 + 1 =  2 5 17 29 61 197  y^2 + 1 =  37 641
129     k: 7742  y:  8   x:  62418  k^2 + 1 =  5 877 13669  y^2 + 1 =  5 13
130     k: 7938  y:  63   x:  500157  k^2 + 1 =  5 13 601 1613  y^2 + 1 =  2 5 397
131     k: 8150  y:  13   x:  106263  k^2 + 1 =  41 677 2393  y^2 + 1 =  2 5 17
132     k: 8192  y:  64   x:  524352  k^2 + 1 =  5 53 157 1613  y^2 + 1 =  17 241
133     k: 8450  y:  65   x:  549315  k^2 + 1 =  53 157 8581  y^2 + 1 =  2 2113
134     k: 8712  y:  66   x:  575058  k^2 + 1 =  5 29 61 8581  y^2 + 1 =  4357
```

Answer (score 1):

I will illustrate the enumeration process with some examples in order to make clear the structure described above.

We start with $k = 1$, the only case with a single solution class $(k, 0)$. We have $k^2+1 = 2$ and $k^2 = 1$. Here is a partial enumeration of all solutions to $x^2 - 2y^2 = 1$:

> ```
>        n            x            y
>        0            1            0
>        1            3            2
>        2           17           12
>        3           99           70
>        4          577          408
>        5         3363         2378
> ```

Because of the symmetry of the equation wrt $k$ and $y$ we know that each pair $(x_n, y_n)$ for $n > 1$ means that $\{y_n \to x_n, 1\}$ is an exceptional solution. For example, we can see that $17^2 - (12^2 + 1).1^2 = 12^2$. Clearly $1 < 12-1$, and so $k = 12$ has an exceptional solution, and because it came from an enumeration of a root class $(1, 0)$ it is a type-1 solution and so we add $12$ to the set $K_1$. 
For all $k > 1$ we have 3 root classes, $(k, 0)$, $(k^2-k+1, k-1)$ and $(k^2-k+1, -k+1)$. Partial enumerations for $k=2$ are shown below:

> ```
>        n            x            y
>        0            2            0
>        1           18            8
>        2          322          144
>        3         5778         2584
>        4       103682        46368
>        5      1860498       832040
> ```

*n            x            y*
       0            3            1
       1           47           21
       2          843          377
       3        15127         6765
       4       271443       121393

*n            x            y*
       0            3           -1
       1            7            3
       2          123           55
       3         2207          987
       4        39603        17711
       5       710647       317811


Each $y_n$ where $n>0$ (or $n>1$ for the 3rd class) provides an exceptional solution $\{y_n \to x_n, 2\}$, and so each $y_n$ is added to $K_1$.
Now every value we add to $K_1$ is an exceptional solution of the form $\{k \to x,y\}$, so for each $k$ in $K_1$ we have an additional pair of conjugate solution classes $(x, \pm{y})$. Assuming the Dujella conjecture is true, these will always be the 4th and 5th classes.
We simply enumerate these classes in similar fashion, except we add the  new $y_n$ values to the list $K_2$, since they come from these additional classes for $k \in K_1$, not from the 3 root classes. For example taking exceptional solution $\{18 \to 8,2\}$, we enumerate the classes $(8, 2)$ and $(8, -2)$ for $k=18$:

> ```
>        n            x            y
>        0            18           2
>        1          4402         546
>        2       1135698      140866
>        3     293005682    36342882
> ```

*n            x            y*
       0            18          -2
       1           242          30
       2         62418        7742
       3      16103602     1997406

Again, every $(x_n, y_n)$ for $n>0$ gives a new exceptional solution $\{y_n \to x_n,18\}$, and so we add each $y_n$ to $K_2$. And every item $k$ we add to $K_2$ represents 2 new classes for that $k$, so we can apply the same procedure recursively to each and every one.
The reason that I have kept $K_1$ and $K_2$ as two distinct lists is that the members of $K_1$ have properties not shared by $K_2$.  The divisibility property noted above is one such property, another is the fact that all of the root classes for any $k$, from which we poulate $K_1$, have explicit polynomial descriptions, which lend themselves to the sort of analysis that we can't readily apply to $K_2$.
For example, we can (I believe) deduce from the properties of these polynomials that every operation "add $y_n$ to $K_1$" provides a unique value. It remains to be seen whether we can prove the same holds for $K_2$.